# GAE template code to check is item in the list

Tags: python, google-app-engine, templates

How to use "in" statement to check is item in the list or not. If I use:

```
{% for picture in pictures %}
   {% if picture in article.pictures %}
      <input type="checkbox" checked="true" name="picture" value="{{ picture.key }}"  />
   {% else %}
      <input type="checkbox" name="picture" value="{{ picture.key }}"  />
   {% endif %}
      <img src='/img?img_id={{ picture.key }}'></img> <br />
{% endfor %}
```

this is failing with:

```
TemplateSyntaxError: 'if' statement improperly formatted
```

on line

```
{% if picture in article.pictures %}
```

help?

Comment: Assuming Django templates, looks like it may be in Django 1.2 (http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8087).  Don't know if that helps you, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Django templates do not support full conditional expressions. You can check if one value is "true" with if, or you can check whether two values are equal with `ifequal`, etc.

Perhaps you can decorate your `picture`s in the view before you render the template.

```
for picture in pictures:
    picture.is_in_article = (picture in article.pictures)
```

Then in the template you can act on the value of that new attribute.

```
{% for picture in pictures %}
    {% if picture.is_in_article %}
        <input type="checkbox" checked="true" name="picture" value="{{ picture.key }}"  />
    {% else %}
        <input type="checkbox" name="picture" value="{{ picture.key }}"  />
    {% endif %}
    <img src='/img?img_id={{ picture.key }}'></img> <br />
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've not worked with GAE, but the code for a custom "ifin" Django tag can be found in the patch [here](http://code.djangoproject.com/attachment/ticket/8087/django-ifin-templatetag.patch).  As mentioned in my comment, it looks like that functionality may be implemented in Django 1.2

Comment: Thanks, I will see can I use it on GAE